# Is a typescript module augmentation automatically exported in a component library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, module-augmentation

I created a component library using `material-ui` and Typescript under the hood. I have used Typescript module augmentation in order to add new options to the theme, as described in [their theme customization with Typescript](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#customization-of-theme) documentation.

```js
// createPalette.d.ts/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
import { Palette, PaletteOptions } from "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette";
declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette" {
    interface Palette {
        highlight: PaletteColor;
        layout: LayoutPaletteColor;
    }
    interface PaletteOptions {
        highlight: PaletteColorOptions;
        layout?: LayoutPaletteColor;
    }
    interface LayoutPaletteColorOptions {
        paper: string;
        text: string;
    }

    interface SidebarPaletteColorOptions extends LayoutPaletteColorOptions {
        navItemSelectedBg: string;
        navItemSelectedColor: string;
    }
    interface LayoutPaletteColor {
        header: LayoutPaletteColorOptions;
        sidebar: SidebarPaletteColorOptions;
        footer: LayoutPaletteColorOptions;
    }
}
```

Then, I build my project and publish it to Github packages. I'm also using this script which copies the `*.d.ts` files to the `dist` folder

`"copy-typings": "copyfiles -u 1 \"./src/types/*.d.ts\" dist",`

When I install the package in another project and reference the Header, for example, I get this error

`Cannot read property 'header' of undefined` which points at the line where the `theme.palette.layout.header.paper` is referenced.

[image: error]

This makes me believe that my `createPalette.d.ts` is only being effective on the component library itself, but not when the components are being used in another project.

How to export this module augmentation? Or how to make this work?

Comment: Add an import to the file containing the augmentation to the entry points of your library. A bare import `import "./augmentations";`

Comment: That didn't help

Comment: Wait... I just realized you're getting a runtime error. That has nothing to do with augmentations in a `.d.ts` file which contains only declarations. You have a different problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Has anyone been able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Just use something else other than Material UI... 
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/materialui-is-a-tech-debt-for-scalable-front-end-applications-4412c81ec9ee

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution to your problem.

TL;DR

1. You should include your `d.ts` files or containing folder in `package.json`

```
...
files: [
  "dist",
  "src/types" or "src/types/global.d.ts"
]
...
```

2. Specify global types in your `tsconfig.json`

```
"types": ["node", "@YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/src/types"]
```

By default TS includes global definition files from `@types` folders. The `"types"` property [tells](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types) it to include some certain d.ts files from other folders. I don't know exactly how it works, but this fixed exactly same problem in my project.

My explanation is very poor, but I hope you will get an idea) Hope it helps